# How could I remove odrive from Explorer's sidebar, remove odrive completely?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

**What is [odrive](https://www.odrive.com/)?**
The application is supposed to link up with all your cloud accounts, and you could reach your files without having them on your computer. Kinda like how Wuala worked, and also ADrive works. Except this application tries to operate with sparse files.

The idea is all great in theory. But in reality, the application is very clunky. Reaching the files is cumbersome and slow, and every cloud provider got some real huge delay, so the whole idea is kinda DOA. They advertise the application with "be the biggest freeloader schmuck in the digital world, and use up all the free space at all the providers!". That tells a lot already.

**What's the issue / question:**
Once you install odrive, it tries to integrate itself (yuck) with the system, as much as possible.
Sadly, when you uninstall the application, some parts remain on your computer.

[image: picture]

The left-side `odrive` folder is one of these things.

Comment: If you right click it and go on properties, does it have a location assigned still?

Comment: @Sam3000 Nope. If I click open folder, that also gives me an error. Attached the properties window: http://i.imgur.com/kjVqDng.jpg

Comment: Are there any registry entries for `odrive`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay - possible solution here:

```
Press 'Windows Key' + Q
Type: regedit
Open regedit as admin.
Go to this folder: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace
```

Delete any references to "odrive" within that folder.

Comment: Just in case, it's `Desktop` instead of `MyComputer` on Windows 10.

Comment: It had a totally random string, no "odrive" or anything, but deleting the random folder from there fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Comment: @Shiki You probably just oversaw it, the folder within is just a `GUID` but inside that folder there is a key names `(Default)` with the value `odrive`.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem as well on Mac OS X Yosemite, even though I thought I had uninstalled odrive successfully.
I right clicked on the remaining folder in the sidebar, clicked 'show in enclosing folder', and then was able to move the entire odrive folder to the trash from there.